# iOS - problems with NSURLAuthenticationChallenge - connection successful but can't access server

Tags: ios, authentication, webserver

I am using NSURLAuthenticationChallenge to log in to a webserver through my app.  All the server requires is a username and a password.    Here is what's happening:

(1) Ping server with POST message containing a User-Agent string in the HTML header

(2) Server responds with an authentication challenge which is detected by the **didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge** delegate method

(3) Respond by sending a challenge response using username and password:

```
NSURLCredential *cred = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:unameTextField.text           
                                                         password:pswdTextField.text
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

(4) If username/password are correct, delegate method **connectionDidFinishLoading** gets called, detecting that the challenge response was accepted by the server.  User is now logged in and can send/receive messages from the server. (If username/password are incorrect, delegate method **didFailWithError** gets called and user is shown an alert.)

Here's where it's going wrong: the very first time I open my Xcode project and run the app and attempt to login with the correct username/password, there is a time lag of 10-15 seconds between steps 3 and 4.  And then even after **connectionDidFinishLoading** is called, when I send messages to the server requesting files it responds by sending me the HTML login page which is the default behavior for unauthenticated requests...so it seems as though I'm not logged in after all.

If I stop and then run the app again there is no lag and everything works fine.

**EDIT: I solved the above problem by clearing the URLCache, all cookies and all credentials before each login attempt.  Code for these 3 methods is below:**

```
- (void)clearCookiesForURL 
{

  NSURL *loginUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.MYURL.com"];
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookiesForURL:loginUrl];
  for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) 
  {
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
  }         
}

- (void)eraseCredentials 
{
    NSString *urlString = @"www.MYURL.com";
    NSURLCredentialStorage *credentialsStorage = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
    NSDictionary *allCredentials = [credentialsStorage allCredentials];

    if ([allCredentials count] > 0) 
    {
      for (NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace in allCredentials) 
      {
        if ([[protectionSpace host] isEqualToString:urlString])
        {
            NSDictionary *credentials = [credentialsStorage credentialsForProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
            for (NSString *credentialKey in credentials)
            {
              [credentialsStorage removeCredential:[credentials objectForKey:credentialKey] forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
            }
        }
      }       
    }
}

- (void)eraseURLCache 
{
    NSURL *loginUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.MYURL.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:loginUrl];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:urlRequest];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
}
```

Another problem: if I wait for a long time between sending message requests to the server while the app is running, the server thinks I've logged out and exhibits the same behavior described above.

**EDIT: this 2nd problem remains unsolved.  Additional information - it appears that the magic time lag number is 10 seconds.  In other words, if I wait more than 10 seconds after the server has authenticated me to request a file from the server, it doesn't recognize my request and sends me the web login page instead, just as it would do for an unauthenticated request.**

Any idea what's going on?  And no, I can't simply load the webserver login page inside my app, because that doesn't meet the requirements for this project.

Comment: Have you tried hitting it with a GET request before the POST?

Comment: I changed the POST to a GET and I immediately get a challenge from the server, so there's no chance to send a separate POST immediately after the GET.  Unfortunately I'm still observing the same behavior.

Perhaps I should do the authentication challenge steps prior to sending any messages?  That seems like overkill though.

Comment: What I was thinking is that you might not be able to POST data to your server before authenticating.  If you do a GET, authenticate, and then on success go ahead and send your message, that might work.  Give it a shot!

Comment: I actually solved the first problem by clearing the URLCache, cookies and credential storage before each login attempt.